# How can I remove a icon which hovers on all my website pages

Tags: magento2

I need to remove a icon which is conneted to a link and it hover in all the pages, as you scroll down.

Comment: If you want to remove this then you need to update your file code with question. you can check here may be that was added in this file.. **app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml**. Please update this file's code here in question.

Comment: @Kishan Savaliya Updated the code. Thanks

Comment: You can check this file **app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Theme/templates/html/footer.phtml**

Comment: @Kishan Savaliya I have updated the code, the code is actually in there but when i remove it, it still not going. Can you suggest me what part to remove. Thanks

Comment: Please check my answer

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot..

Comment: You're welcome Buddy! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to remove this line from your `footer.phtml` file

```
<div class="kwc-btn-float"> <a class=" kwc-floating" href="http://devnew.kiabza.com/account/pick-up/" target="_blank" title="Request a Pick Up"><i class="fa fa-truck"></i> Request a Pick Up </a> </div>
```

and then **clear and flush Magento cache from Backend**.

Hope this will work for you!